Arch linux: Can not connect to Lenovo dock gen 2 using thunderbolt
I have this hardware:

Lenovo thinkpad x390 yoga
Lenovo thinkpad thunderbolt 3 dock gen 2/Workstation dock gen 2

and this software: Wayland + sway
I would like to be able to connect laptop to the dock and it will charge it and connects external display using HDMI or display port.
None of these think is happening.
What should I do to be able to use the dock ?
Thankyou for help
Diagnostics
cat /proc/version outputs
Linux version 6.9.7-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 14.1.1 20240522, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.42.0) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 28 Jun 2024 04:32:50 +0000

lspci | grep -i thunder outputs
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
08:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
08:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
09:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
2f:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)

In journalctl -p 3 -xb is this:
Jul 06 17:08:43 archlinux kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: con1: failed to register alt modes
Jul 06 17:08:43 archlinux kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
Jul 06 17:09:14 archlinux acpid[1453]: cannot open input layer
Jul 06 17:09:14 archlinux acpid[1453]: can't open socket /var/run/acpid.socket: Address already in use
Jul 06 17:09:15 archlinux sudo[1514]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jul 06 17:09:15 archlinux sudo[1514]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [john]
Jul 06 17:09:17 archlinux sudo[2072]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jul 06 17:09:17 archlinux sudo[2072]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [john]

I have these packages installed:

local/bolt 0.9.8-1

Thunderbolt 3 device manager


local/plasma-thunderbolt 6.1.2-1 (plasma)

Plasma integration for controlling Thunderbolt devices


local/tbtools 0.4.1-1

Collection of tools for Linux Thunderbolt/USB4 development, debugging and validation



systemctl status bolt.service outputs
● bolt.service - Thunderbolt system service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bolt.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-07-06 17:08:40 CEST; 24min ago
 Invocation: 391ae69c33e947c9aa0b9dde79bdc8b6
       Docs: man:boltd(8)
   Main PID: 1015 (boltd)
     Status: "authmode: enabled, force-power: unset"
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18738)
     Memory: 1.6M (peak: 2.3M)
        CPU: 153ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bolt.service
             └─1015 /usr/lib/boltd

Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: udev: enumerating devices
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: probing: adding /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:07:00.0 to roots
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-domain0                    ] bootacl: synchronizing journal
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: security level set to 'user'
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-domain0                    ] connected: as domain0 [user] (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/domain0)
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-X390-YOGA                  ] parent is (null)...
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-X390-YOGA                  ] connected: authorized (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:07:00.0/0000:08:00.0/0000:09:00.0/domain0/0-0)
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-domain0                    ] dbus: exported domain at /org/freedesktop/bolt/domains/d7030000_00a2_a088_a074_8e242873d324
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux boltd[1015]: [d7030000-00a2-X390-YOGA                  ] dbus: exported device at /org/freedesktop/bolt/devices/d7030000_00a2...
Jul 06 17:08:40 archlinux systemd[1]: Started Thunderbolt system service.

boltctl list does not output anything
boltctl list --all outputs
 ● Lenovo X390-YOGA
   ├─ type:          host
   ├─ name:          X390-YOGA
   ├─ vendor:        Lenovo
   ├─ uuid:          d7030000-00a2-a088-a074-8e242873d324
   ├─ generation:    Thunderbolt 3
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     d7030000-00a2-a088-a074-8e242873d324
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ authorized:    Sat Jul  6 15:08:38 2024
   ├─ connected:     Sat Jul  6 15:08:38 2024
   └─ stored:        Sun May 26 12:38:48 2024
      ├─ policy:     manual
      └─ key:        no

lsmod | grep thunderbolt outputs
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
thunderbolt           565248  0
wmi                    36864  4 video,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,think_lmi

What I tried

Rebooting
Updating kernel
Updating firmware


Not even the charging works? This doesn't sound like a software problem. Do you have any other operating systems to test with? If the machine came with some form of Windows, have you tried booting into that and seeing if it works? Anecdotally, I have been using this (non-thunderbolt) dock with Arch on my 14s for a couple of years, and I used a similar one with my old T14s for many years. I suspect your dock is faulty (but I don't know much about this).

When I connect it and start my laptop BIOS will display message that charging has not enough voltage. I think it is because charged device should "ask" for proper voltage like on USB-C.
